# Send element from BeautifulSoup to Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am using Selenium to navigate a webpage. To analyze the elements and data, I use BeautifulSoup because of the excellent options they give, including searching with regex.

So now I have an element located in BeautifulSoup. I want to select it in Selenium.

I figured I could somehow pass a XPath or CSS selector from the BeautifulSoup element to the Selenium element.

Is there a direct way of going from a BeautifulSoup element to Selenium element?

Comment: I am unsure of what you are asking or trying to achieve. Selenium will return a WebElement on lookup and this can be interacted with. It is designed to give control/interaction and observation for testing. BeautifuSoup is designed to format data into a more human readable format.. What is your intended work flow? are you trying to create test reports?

Answer (score 0):

These are completely different tools that, in general, cannot be considered alternatives, though they somewhat cross on the "Locating Elements" front. The located elements though are very different - one is a `Tag` instance in `BeautifulSoup` and the other one is a webdriver `WebElement` instance that can actually be interacted with it is "live".

Both tools support CSS selectors. The support is quite different, but if you don't go in depth with things like multiple attribute checks (`a[class*=test1][class^=test]` - not gonna work in `BeautifulSoup`, for instance), `nth-child`, `nth-of-type`, going sideways with `+` etc, you can assume things are gonna work on both ends.

Please add examples of the elements you want to correlate and we can work through them.